# Greendao - String Property comparison should be case insensitive

Tags: java, android, greendao

How can I make the String comparison case insensitive without using String manipulation's toLowercase/toUppercase

```
QueryBuilder qb = mPropertyModelDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where(PropertyModelDao.Properties.City.eq(cityCode));
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the behaviors of `String.compareTo` or `String.equals`.

A couple of ideas for "doing it differently":

- You could convert the property value (either as passed by the setter, or as returned by the getter) to all lowercase or all uppercase.
- You could have your property getters return the property values in a custom `CharSequence` that does comparisons case insensitively.
- You could do the comparison using a `Comparator`.

---

<sup>If the real problem here is that your database contains "city code" values in mixed cases (e.g. "sydney" and "Sydney") then you should probably fix that problem first ... by updating the database content to use a consistent case.</sup>